# Crop svg circle object with rect object

Tags: svg, crop, geometry, shapes, rect

Trying to crop a circle object within a rect box.

```
<rect class="cls-2" x="36.21" y="74.47" width="237.17" height="123.78"></rect>
<circle class="cls-3" data-name="effector" class="cls-4" cx="234.79" cy="137.14" r="31.81"></circle>
```

Both are shapes imported from illustrator SVGs. 
But when I put the circle within the rect object, the circle disappears.

```
<rect class="cls-2" x="36.21" y="74.47" width="237.17" height="123.78">
<circle class="cls-3" data-name="effector" class="cls-4" cx="234.79" cy="137.14" r="31.81"></circle>
</rect>
```

Trying to avoid using clipPath since it doesn't work in IE. 
Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/phantomboogie/cya2r55e/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a `<circle>` element inside a `<rect>` element. That's invalid SVG.

> Trying to avoid using clipPath since it doesn't work in IE.

I'm not sure what you mean by this.  clipPaths work fine in IE.

https://jsfiddle.net/cya2r55e/2/

Comment: Looked it up on caniuse and it says its not valid. http://caniuse.com/#search=clippath 

Is caniuse outdated?

Comment: That caniuse page is referring to the clipping of *HTML* content with SVG clipping paths or CSS shapes.  That is different from the clipping of SVG content with SVG clipping paths, which is fine.